# Meteor 1.3 including npm package on client

Tags: javascript, meteor, import, npm

I am building an app using Meteor 1.3 and want to use the Push.js library from here: https://nickersoft.github.io/push.js/

Following the Meteor docs it mentions that tools like Browserify are not needed as it's handled out of the box, but is there something specific I will need to import this module on the client side?

I've tried to import via the line below on the server side

```
import Push from 'push.js';
```

But Push comes back as undefined on click.

When I try the same import on the client side it tells me unexpected token import.

In the push.js demo they just call the min.push.js file in script tags and Push.create() works as needed.

Thank you!

Comment: When you say it comes back as undefined, is that when meteor compiles/runs or are you trying to access push from the browser console?

Comment: I'm trying to create a notification on click similar to the demo at this link below and the error shows up in console. http://nickersoft.github.io/push.js/demo.html

Comment: At what point are you getting the undefined error though? And can you post the command you added the npm package to meteor with?

Comment: `meteor npm install --save push.js` for installation. In regards to the error, I tried a few different methods and have gotten the error on the click itself, but I believe that was when I imported on the serverside. I don't believe the import ever worked client side. I'll edit the original issue above to be more clear, sorry!